# Send a link that redirects back to the Detail page of the Object

Tags: trigger, email, salesforce-id, url, detail-page

I have created an trigger which is sent an email to the user every time a user is created and they are welcomed and reminded to complete the KYC Process.

How should I send a URL in the body of the mail which redirects back to the Detail page of the Customer object?

This is my code:

```
trigger EmailTriggerOnCustomer on Customer__c (before insert) {
    //List<Customer__c> customerEmail = [SELECT id, Email__C from Customer__c];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    
    for(Customer__c cus : trigger.new){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        
        //List of people receiving the mail
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
        sendTo.add(cus.Email__C);
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        
        //Set where the email is sent from
        mail.setReplyTo('bobita.singha53@gmail.com');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Bank Administrator');
        
        //set email content
        mail.setSubject('Fill your KYC Details for Verification');
        String body = 'Dear ' + cus.Name + ', ';
        body += '<br> Please complete your KYC Verification process by filling the details to open your Bank Account.';
        
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        
        mails.add(mail);
        
    }
    if(mails.size() > 0)
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```

and i want to redirect back to this page. The customer shall have redirect back to its own detail page. Please help. - [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please drop a Salesforce link into your body details as follows,

```
//set email content
        mail.setSubject('Fill your KYC Details for Verification');
        String body = 'Dear ' + cus.Name + ', ';
        body += '<br> Please complete your KYC Verification process by filling the details to open your Bank Account.';
        body += '<br> https://yourinstance.my.salesforce.com/'+cus.id;
```

Then the receiver user can able to redirect into `details page` by using that link.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: it is not reading the id - https://empathetic-panda-i5er71-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Customer__c/null

Comment: You're going to send an email to user once after the customer record is created right?

Comment: If it's Yes, Please make your trigger fire in "After Insert". then you can able to get the ID Value without issue.

Comment: Yes you're right. That was my use case. And after trigger helped fetch the id. But now its showing another error. When the URL is clicked its saying- 'This record is no longer available. Ask your administrator for help.'

Comment: Please check the record is whether available in your org or any user or other process will delete the record.

Comment: The record is not getting deleted, its present but the page is not opening.

Comment: OKay, then please check the user (who click the link) access for the customer object is sufficient to access the record page. And please check as the link is fully formatted without any issues (by just copy & paste as your user/system admin)

Comment: Hey, it's working. It was a problem with the URL. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation. Please accept the answer, It's SFSE culture, Which is helpful for other users also which having the same doubt in forward days.